# Nginx "fastcgi_temp_path" no files exists?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, php

a Question of Nginx and PHP-FPM

I have read the entire of http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFcgiModule

If a php file return a big content from FastCGI, in my mind, Nginx will cache all of the content, closing the conversation with PHP-FPM, sent the content to browser

If the client is low (lots of seconds to receive), and the content bigger and all of buffer settings

example:

php script:

```
<?php
$t = time();
for ($i = 1; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    echo str_repeat(".", 1000);
    echo " [ $i ] ";
}
echo " ".(time() - $t);
```

nginx setting:

```
fastcgi_buffer_size                 1k;
fastcgi_buffers                     2 2k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size           2k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size        2k;
fastcgi_temp_path                   /tmp/nginxcache 1 2;
fastcgi_store          on;
fastcgi_store_access   user:rw  group:rw  all:rw;
```

and nginx vhost setting for watch:

```
limit_rate 5k;
```

When I run a cURL, I can see php run in < 1 sec (end of content is the time). but I can't find any files (sudo find /tmp/nginxcache, only some empty directories) whole I receiving the content.

Where is buffers store ? memory or files ? what's wrong in my setting?

Thanks.